# Creating a macOS AddressBook Action Plug-In in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to create a minimal action plugin for macOS AddressBook in Swift.  My starting point is the Xcode-created ObjC default template which consists of

```
ContactsActionPluginObjC.h
ContactsActionPluginObjC.m
```

and

```
Info.plist
```

What I did was to delete `ContactsActionPluginObjC.h` and `ContactsActionPluginObjC.m` from the Xcode project, and add a `SwiftFile.swift` in their place:

```
import Cocoa
import AddressBook

class SwiftFile {
    func actionProperty() -> String! {
        return kABPhoneProperty
    }

    func title(for: ABPerson!, identifier: String!) -> String! {
        return "SomeText"
    }

    func performAction(for: ABPerson!, identifier: String!) {
        return
    }

    func shouldEnableAction(for: ABPerson!, identifier:String!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I have also adjusted `Principal class` in `Info.plist` to `SwiftFile`. This builds without errors.  However, when I copy the resulting `.bundle` file into `~/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins` and then start macOS Contacts, the plugin does not show up in the context menu of a contact phone number.

Placing the compiled `.bundle` file of the ObjC template in the same location, the ObjC-based action shows up as expected.

What is missing / what am I overlooking: why does the Swift version not work?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is missing / what am I overlooking: why does the Swift version not work?

Comment: The Swift libraries are missing?

Comment: @Willeke How would I make sure they are in the bundle?